# Renaming output of a command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, foreach, powershell-3.0

I am using Mp4box in order to split a file into one minute parts, normally Mp4box use file_nnn.mp4 where the n are like 001, 002, 003, ....
I would like to rename it to partn.mp4 where n is also an increasing odd number.
I use this code but it is not working.

```
Mp4box -split 60 file.mp4 | foreach- 
object -begin {$c=1} -process rename- 
item $_ -newname "part$c.mp4"; 
$c=$c+2 }
```

Comment: Missing a bracket? `-process { rename-item $_ -newname "part$c.mp4"; $c=$c+2}`

Comment: So whats the output of just `Mp4box -split 60 file.mp4`

Comment: It is file_xxx.mp4 where xxx increases, I posted it.

Comment: I mean is the output strings or are they files on the harddrive. I mean is mp4box a powershell command? If Mp4box -split 60 file.mp4 doesnt output string or objects that powershell understands then you cant really use powershell like you have it. Like what is the exact output of Mp4box in powershell. Please post output in the post so we can help with how to fix this script.

Answer (score 0):

So lets talk about what you have wrong.

```
Mp4box -split 60 file.mp4 |
    foreach-object -begin {$c=1} -process 
rename-item $_ -newname "part$c.mp4"; 
$c=$c+2
}
```

This is not a valid powershell statement. 
The beginning is fine but after the first pipe **|** you then use a incomplete foreach-object with the parameters -process and -begin but they are separated by the foreach block where you create a variable **$c** that cant be seen by the rest of the script because its scope is confined to the foreach. You then have a rename-item that is outside the pipe **|** and then try to use a piped variable **$_** which will be null because it is outside the pipe **|**. Finally you add 2 to **$c** which is null becuase its outside the scope of the **$c** in the foreach. You also add closing bracket **}** when there is no opening bracket.

Here is a working script which fully depends on the output of Mp4box. If Mp4box is not a powershell command and is instead a executable then this will not work.

```
$C = 1
Mp4box -split 60 file.mp4 |
    %{
        rename-item $_ -newname "part$c.mp4"
        $C += 2
     }
```

Lets go over whats above. I call $C = 1 outside the foreach so its usable in the foreach scope.

I pipe | the output of Mp4box to a **%** which is shorthand for **foreach-object** .

Inside the **%** (foreach-object) brackets **{ }** it renames the item **$_** from the pipe **|**.

Then it adds 2 to c using shorthand for **+=** which is the same as add to **($C = $C + 2)**

Now again this purely relies on if the output of Mp4box.

Comment: I can't vote you up but thank you very much for the perfect exploration.

Comment: well when you can upvote please come back and do so. Takes time to write these

Comment: Of course, mp4box is a media multiplexer like ffmpeg that can split files, it has advanced concepts too.

Comment: Unfortunately, since mp4box is not a PowerShell command, this script does not work.

Comment: yeah like i said depends on if it was a powershell command :/

Comment: maybe but i would need to know exactly what happens when you run `Mp4box -split 60 file.mp4`

Comment: Assume file.mp4 is a 3 minute video, the output will be file_001.mp4, file_002.mp4, file_003.mp4.